# Discord.py - How to assign a role after month of membership in the server?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm making a Discord bot in Python and I want to add a feature so the bot will automatically assign a `Member` role to the user, who is a member of this server for a month. Then, after 1 month since the `Member` role was assigned, the bot automatically deletes `Member` role and assigns `Member 2` role.

Here's what I have tried to do:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send(
        "Welcome to our server, mate! I recommend you to read our rules, to make your experience here super comfy!")
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id='893928735496101908')
    await member.add_roles(role)
#This is the code when the member joins and, presumably, achieves a role.
#But how to make it delete the role and make a new one once 1 month passes, I don't know
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What have you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: Hi Taku! I've just edited my question :)